# adding flower to celery daemon?

Tags: python, celery, flower

Is it possible to add flower to the celery daemon?

Below is my celery config file, I tried added flower config to the CELERYD_OPTS variable but it has failed.

or is there another command I can add to the config file to get flower up and running with celery?

```
# Names of nodes to start
#   most people will only start one node:
CELERYD_NODES="worker1"
#   but you can also start multiple and configure settings
#   for each in CELERYD_OPTS
#CELERYD_NODES="worker1 worker2 worker3"
#   alternatively, you can specify the number of nodes to start:
#CELERYD_NODES=10

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="/usr/local/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
# comment out this line if you don't use an app
CELERY_APP="itapp"
# or fully qualified:
#CELERY_APP="proj.tasks:app"

# Where to chdir at start.
CELERYD_CHDIR="/itapp/itapp/"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="flower --ports 5555 --time-limit=300 --concurrency=8"
# Configure node-specific settings by appending node name to arguments:
#CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 -c 8 -c:worker2 4 -c:worker3 2 -Ofair:worker1"

# Set logging level to DEBUG
#CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="DEBUG"

# %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
#   You need to create this user manually (or you can choose
#   a user/group combination that already exists (e.g., nobody).
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"

# If enabled pid and log directories will be created if missing,
# and owned by the userid/group configured.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

Comment: I'm not sure `celery_opts` are meant to fire off another process (that is what flower is if I understand correctly. Even if you do get it using the config, it's probably wrong. Why not just start both separately (you can create a script that starts both)?

Comment: I need another daemon process for flower? I'm not sure how to do that, I followed this guide to do it for celery https://pythad.github.io/articles/2016-12/how-to-run-celery-as-a-daemon-in-production. and I can't find one for celery

Comment: I googled this: https://github.com/mher/flower/issues/28 but perhaps google how to start flower, because it is a separate process and server.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest run them with `supervisord` or [other process control system](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1368855), rather than OS init script and start-stop-daemon.

Both worker and flower should run as daemon process side by side, there are [many docs on how to run celery worker with supervisord](https://micropyramid.com/blog/celery-with-supervisor/), run flower is simply to add another program section, replace worker command with corresponding flower launching command like `celery flower -A itapp --ports 5555 --time-limit=300 --concurrency=8`.

Comment: im using python 3 which, is not currently supported by supervisord

Comment: supercisord run program as binary executable, nothing to do with python 2 or 3, however, you could stick with init, just hold the idea run flower as a standalone daemon.